# Traffic Dip because of wrong schema code?

Tags: schema.org, search-results, traffic

I just added a "job post schema code" on my page. And then i noticed that the traffic for that page dropped down. Below is the code, Can anyone tell me is this code all good? I checked it with Google structured data tester it just had few warnings without any errors.

**This is the page** - www.tutorvista.com/teaching-jobs

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context" : "http://schema.org/",
  "@type" : "JobPosting",
  "educationRequirements": "B.Tech, B.Sc. or M.Sc, M.Tech, M.phil & Ph.d only",
  "industry": "Online Tutoring",
  "employmentType": "Part-time",
  "title" : "Online Tutoring Jobs - Tutorvista",
  "description" : "<p>We are hiring a large number of qualified and committed tutors. If online teaching interests you, come and grab an exciting work opportunity!</p>
  <p>TutorVista is the leading player in the online tutoring space. Join us and work for a rapidly growing company with immense possibilities for career advancement. With an online teaching job, you get to do what you enjoy doing - teaching and sharing your knowledge with students online.</p>",

  "datePosted" : "2017-07-26",
  "hiringOrganization" : {
  "@type" : "Organization",
  "name" : "Tutorvista Global Pvt Ltd",
  "sameAs" : "http://www.tutorvista.com"
  },
  "jobLocation" : {
 "@type" : "Place",
 "address" : {
 "@type" : "PostalAddress",
  "streetAddress" : "IBC Knowledge Park, Tower C 5th Floor, Bannerghatta Main Rd",
  "addressLocality" : "Bhavani Nagar, Suddagunte Palya",
  "addressRegion" : "KA",
  "postalCode" : "560046",
  "addressCountry": "IN"
    }
   }
   }
  </script>
```

Might this be the reason for the traffic drop? if not, what else can be? Any ideas?

Below is the Traffic Data. (there's a **dip at the end of august**, that's when i published it)

[image]

**Thank you**

Comment: Google does have a rich snippet for job postings:  https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/job-postings with incorrect schema for it, you would have lost that special treatment.   The only way this could have accounted for your dip is if all your lost clicks were coming from Google's rich snippets.

Comment: oh okay, but is the above mentioned schema incorrect? it just has got some warnings though.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen incorrect or incomplete schema show negative results in more than one situation, most of the time its over usage or non consistent information.

Going as far to say that in some cases it was better not to have schema at all. ( Only in some cases )

The single most important thing is to make sure your NAP ( Name, Address, Phone ) is consistent, regardless or not if its a localised target, its important to show consistency.

So in your example I personally wouldn't have "Tutorvista Global Pvt Ltd" as your organisation Name as its not consistent with other influential profiles around the internet, you can see that Google uses your Wikipedia entry as a search Snippet.  So for your organisation I would use "TutorVista" and nothing more.

Obviously that's just an example, and it may not be the cause of the dip.  But split testing consistency and the "fetch as google bot" in search console will be your friend to speed up your testing process.